# How native an application built using RubyMotion or Rubuto can be?

Tags: native, rubymotion, ruboto, nativeapplication

On the RubyMotion site's home page, They say it's a

```
revolutionary toolchain that lets you quickly develop and test native iOS and OS X
applications for iPhone, iPad and Mac
```

On the Rubuto framework site, they say something similar

```
Ruboto is a framework and tool chain to develop native Android apps, using the Ruby
language we all know and love.
```

How can apps developed using those frameworks be called native applications?

Answer (score 3):

The RubyMotion toolchain compiles directly against the Objective-C runtime and API's, the same as Objective-C.

RubyMotion code compiles into **native** machine code, just as an Obj-C app will.

http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/guides/runtime/

Thus, these two snippets of code return the same thing:

Obj-C:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

RubyMotion:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.delegate
```

RubyMotion -> compile -> machine code

Objective-C -> compile -> machine code

Answer (score 2):

Ruboto apps can be called native since from the outside they cannot be distinguished from apps developed in Java.  They are not just scripts running on another app.  They are self contained, standalone apps accessing the Android API directly.